How do I create a database based on such a class structure in C#/EF Core?
There is such a class structure:

Using such a structure, EF does not allow me to create a database, since there are three properties of the same type in the ExpertSystem entity, it will be clearer in the sample code:
Entities:
public class ExpertSystem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> InitialOperations { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> CompletionOperations { get; set; }

    public List<Operation> VariablesOperations { get; set; }
}
public class Input : Operation
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Variable Variable { get; set; }

    public int VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Output : Operation
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Variable? Variable { get; set; }
    public int? VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Operation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ExpertSystem ExpertSystem { get; set; }

    public int ExpertSystemId { get; set; }
}
public class Variable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

When trying to create a database, I got an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to determine the
relationship represented by navigation 'Expert
System.CompletionOperations' of type 'List'. Either manually configure
the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
'OnModelCreating'."

Then I tried to configure it through the OnModelCreating() method:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ExpertSystem> ExpertSystems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Variable> Variables { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.InitialOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.CompletionOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.VariablesOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}

I got the same error anyway. Is there any way to fix this? I need, in the essence of the expert system, to divide the links with operations into blocks.

You need to explicitly configure EF on how to handle the derived types. See EF Inheritance

Also, if you just want to save/load your entire model all at once, I would just serialize it as Json instead. Databases are great when you need the features it provide, but it is not the only option.

@JonasH But by default, EF creates one table for all classes when inheriting. From the documentation: "By default, EF maps the inheritance using the table-per-hierarchy (TYPE) pattern. "

Why do you only have one navigation property of type ExpertSystem in Operation to represent three different relationships?

@jmcilhinney Because the entity Operation should be associated with only one ExpertSystem. I thought it was the right thing to do. Do I have to create three separate ExpertSystem properties in an Operation?

I would think so, yes. I've never tested not doing it that way but a navigation property is supposed to represent a relationship - the equivalent of a foreign key in the database. A single column can't be the child of three different foreign keys. I would think the alternative would be to have a single relationship - so a single collection - and have an extra column that indicates what type of operation it is. Maybe I'm wrong about this but I don't see how it would work the way you're doing it.

This should solve your problem:
public class ExpertSystem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Operation> InitialOperations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Operation> CompletionOperations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Operation> VariablesOperations { get; set; }
}
public class Input 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Variable Variable { get; set; }
    public int VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Output
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Variable? Variable { get; set; }
    public int? VariableId { get; set; }
}
public class Operation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ExpertSystem ExpertSystem { get; set; }
    public int ExpertSystemId { get; set; }
}
public class Variable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

And then:
public partial class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{

    public ApplicationDBContext() {

        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("data source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ExpertSystem;integrated security=True;");
        }
    }

    public DbSet<ExpertSystem> ExpertSystems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Output> Outputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Variable> Variables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()

            .HasMany(e => e.InitialOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.CompletionOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ExpertSystem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.VariablesOperations)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.ExpertSystemId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

Database diagram:

And database is successfully created:


The Expert System entity has links to the basic Operation entity, but no links to specific operations (for example, Output). Will I be able to get all the "Output" operations from the initialization block from the "Expert System" entity, for example?

From your initial model, it looks like you have 3 separate tables: input, output and variable. If every expert system can only have one of each of these, then you might consider to link expertsystem to these entities directly, not via Output. Also, in your initial model inly Input and Output extend Operation, while Variable does not... So if Input, Output and Variable are 3 types of operations, you can avoid Operation entity... You could also then combine Input,Output and Variable into one table and add another column to specify the type of operation for each record...

Also, in your initial model, Input and Output have a column Variableid and are linked to Variable table, but Input and Output have no primary keys defined. If there are 3 types of operations, why are Input and Output linked to the 3rd Outcome (Variable) ? That would mean that Expert System us linked to Input, Output and Variable, but Input and Output would also be linked to Variable .. looks like a circular reference ?

@Андрей you can also reach me on Discord (Mario K.) - I hope it does not violate any SO rules...
